# What code fires when a Dynamics Ax 2012 client connects to an AOS?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, aot

Hoping to add some custom functionality for when a client connects to a specific AOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to be more specific, so that an AX Client is **always** connected to an AOS by definition. If you need to make some job on client startup, you have the `SysStartupCmd` class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa569641.aspx

Comment: I was able to do what I needed to do by making a custom `SysStartupCmd`.  Thanks!